# css overriding is not working after addClass()

Tags: jquery, html, css

Before Element:

```
<li id="tabs-abc" class="room current" data-name="abc" data-closed="false" role="tab" data-currenttheme="bright" data-cursor="pointer" style="visibility: visible; cursor: pointer;"></li>
```

'.current' Css:

```
#tabs li.current, #tabs li:hover {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

After this code:

```
this.tab.addClass('dark-tab').show();
```

And css:

```
.dark-tab {
    background-color: #C2C3C4;
}
```

'dark-tab' added successfully but can not override the backgournd color. For current situation I must use jquery to add this css.
Any solution will be highly appreciated

Comment: Google "css specificity" to learn how to control the priority.

Comment: @Barmar For the circumstances I must add it using jquery. How can I apply css specificity using jquery ?

Comment: @Arnab you don't change specificity in jQuery. You change specificity in your CSS rules for `.dark-tab`.

Comment: If you google as I suggest, you'll learn how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your previous selector has higher specificity.

You can change your CSS selector for `.dark-tab` to `#tabs li.dark-tab` to match the previous rule's specificity, or you can use `!important` to override the previous rules' specificity like

```
.dark-tab {
  background-color: #C2C3C4 !important;
}
```

Comment: Just add #tabs li.dark-tab{...} A precise definition is enought. Do not use important if you don't have to. And in this case, you don't have to.

Comment: @Arnab, please check out my previous comment.

Comment: @Ann : Thank you Ann. I will follow your advice. But I think this time I need '!important', as I need to change the theme dynamically using jquery.

Comment: @Arnab Did you tested my css code? I think it will be working without !important. Because the #tabs li.current.dark-tab will be stronger definition. I gave you an answer, please check out.

Comment: @Ann I also gave the parent ID and element name to increase specificity - it was my first suggestion. But also included `!important` as another option. Both are valid. OP can use which ever one works for them with their application.

Comment: @MichaelCoker First of all my comment is poorly drafted. To correct myself : So i wanted to say that, the #tabs li.current.dark-tab definition is stronger like the .dark-tab. I know that both are valid.But I thought a strong definition without important should be enought Yes, that is what you said the first. I think it would be a better solution. That's all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

You have added it, but the initial CSS overrides it. Use one of these:

```
.dark-tab {
    background-color: #C2C3C4 !important;
}

#tabs li.current.dark-tab,
#tabs li.dark-tab:hover {
    background-color: #C2C3C4;
}
```

More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-override-technique/)

### Update

After seeing your comment, you can set the CSS styles that will override every property that doesn't have `!important` by using the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function.

This jQuery work for you:

```
this.tab.css("background", "#C2C3C4").show();
```

If you want a other styles, like a border, you could add additional styles like this:

```
this.tab.css({
              "background": "#C2C3C4",
              "border": "1px solid #000"
                                      }).show();
```

Or as one line:

```
this.tab.css({"background": "#C2C3C4", "border": "1px solid #000"}).show();
```

Comment: The first 3 line is unnesssesary with using important. Just add #tabs li.dark-tab{...} A precise definition is enought.

Comment: @Chris Happy : that will be done dynamically. Can I do this using jquery instead of hard coded css ?

Comment: @Ann He wrote "use one of these", not both.

Answer (score 0):

A precise definition is enought:

```
    #tabs li.dark-tab, #tabs li.dark-tab.current {
        background-color: #C2C3C4;
    }
```

If you do not have to, do not use !important css codes.